# Error al usar Kotlin Android Extensions

Tags: android, kotlin

Estoy usando estas extensiones y todo funciona de maravilla, pero he notado que en ocaciones no realiza el bind correctamente, en módulos como Adapters, ViewHolders y en esta ocasión en un DialogFragment.
Me está arrojando esta excepción:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

Tengo la versión "1.1.4-2" de Kotlin
En el import tengo mi layout:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.layout_dialog_scan.*
```

y en el método onCreateView:

```
val viewRoot = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog_scan, container, false)

img_close.setOnClickListener{ hideViews() }     
edit_code.addTextChangedListener(this)
//.....Más widgets

return viewRoot
```

Este error desaparece si yo realizo el bind con base en la vista:

```
val imageView = viewRoot.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.img_close)
imageView.setOnClickListener{ hideViews() }
```

¿Alguien sabe la posible causa del error?

Comment: Puedes agregar el código completo de la clase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error resultó ser algo simple y obvio.
Al invocar un elemento con esta extensión, internamente realizá una búsqueda:

```
getview().findViewById(R.id.nombre)
```

Mi error era al pintarlo en el método onCreateView(), en esta etapa aún no es creada la vista, la solución simple es usar la invocación de estos widgets en el método onViewCreated().

Aunado a eso encontré algo interesante, para usarlo en una clase ViewHolder de un adapter, extenderla de LayoutContainer: 
[información en ingles](https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-android-extensions/)

Answer (score 2):

El error menciona que no puedes llamar el método `setOnClickListener` en una instancia `ImageView` con valor null:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ImageView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference

No puedes llamar un método de una instancia con valor null de una vista sin antes obtener su referencia mediante:

```
val imageView = viewRoot.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.img_close)
imageView.setOnClickListener{ hideViews() }
```

La obtención de estas referencias y cambiar sus propiedades la puedes realizar dentro del método `onCreate()`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]